# How to add a testrail report to Confluence

Tags: confluence, testrail

I have create a report to track the status of testcases. I am looking to create a dashboard on confluence  using the said report.

I followed the page

https://support.testrail.com/hc/en-us/articles/7169138868116-Integrate-with-Confluence#adding-dashboards-to-confluence-cloud-0-0

Though this page says only main and project dashboards are allowed but I was able to enbedd my testrun url as well. but When I give url for my report and publish my confluene page , I am not able to scroll on generated dashbord

Comment: 1) Can you please share the URL that you used for the iframe configuration in confluence? 2) Can you please share a screenshot of your iframe configuration, so we can see the values you have for height, width, scrolling, and text direction?

Answer (score 0):

TestRail doesn't provide an official public URL for sharing test runs.
It's possible to add an iframe in Confluence cloud with the private URL of one  of your test runs but it will require that you (or whoever will access it) are authenticated in your Jira instance.
In this case I've configured the `iframe` macro on Confluence cloud like this:

`https://xxxx.testrail.io/index.php?/runs/view/1364&group_by=cases:section_id&group_order=asc`

I also set the width, height and scrolling attributes.
This way, scrolling on the iframe works.

[image: iframe attributes configuration]

This will be the final result; once again, it will require the user to be authenticated on TestRail instance and thus it's the possible workaround for the time being.

[image: test run embed on a confluence cloud page]

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved long back . I was using the % for height in confluence parameters. When I used px(ex: 500 px), it worked.

For people still coming across this issue , you can follow the answer posted by Sergio.

Any report will work  though on testrail documentation it is mentioned that only dashboard is supported